# networking in background while app is closed from recent apps

Tags: android, android-service

I want to fetch and send some data when the app is closed, I've already made foreground service but don't know where to use retrofit to that it can run.
I also saw a tutorial to make a foreground app, I'm able to make the app which runs a piece of code in background, but how to perform networking.

[image: code of foreground app]

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use [JobService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService) and [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler) to schedule your jobs. Make your retrofit work in `onStartJob` (don't forget to return `true` from this method). Also don't forget to call `jobFinished()`

Or you can try new [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/)